# Grignard vs organolithium reagent opening cyclohexene oxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Could someone please explain the reason for the two different products formed? One with RLi and the other with RMgBr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\ce{RLi}$ is much more reactive than $\ce{RMgBr}$ and attacks through the SN2 process, thus inversion of configuration occurs. But in case of $\ce{RMgBr}$, $\ce{MgBr-}$ coordinates with epoxide O atom and forms carbocation on the adjacent carbon. Then a $\ce{C-C}$ bond migrates and the above product is formed.

Comment: Do you mind posting a curly-mechanism for this? Ty.